# SQL Server Agent Job - SSIS - C# - "Access denied. " when trying to delete files

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

One of our Jobs that runs an SSIS package for deleting files with a script task (c# File.Delete) behaves in a strange way as below. Could anyone help us understand the reason for it?

Below are the basic conditions:
    1. SQL Server Agent Service's Logon Account: DomainA\AAA
    2. Owner of the Job: DomainA\AAA
    3. DomainA\AAA is a member of local "Administrators" group

What we found strange is:
The job fails with the message "Access to the path E:\XXXX\pp.csv denied" when Full control access is given only to "Administrators" windows group and successes when Full control access is given directly to "DomainA\AAA" windows user.

Before the error message above, it says "The step was executed as: DomainA\AAA".

Version Info:
SQL Server 2008 SP2(10.0.4000)
Windows 2003 R2 x64 SP2

Note:
1. English messages above are my own translation from our language and it wouldn't be accurately equal to the ones in English version.
2. The SSIS package is simplified to have this one script task only for testing.

Comment: Does it say why the access was denied? I usually see that when I have the file open. Is your program running as an administrator?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The job is run by DomainA\AAA, which is a member of "Administartors" group. Could you let us know what's the difference between giving "Full Control" access to a user directly and to a group to which the user belongs?

Answer (score 2):

Can you check weather on the folder you have given all the permission(Read and write) for Administrators group. If this doesn't works please change the folder and try once.

Comment: Yes, I have given Full Control permission for Administrators group but it doesn't work, though once I gave Full Control permission to the user itself, it  worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this blog to get information about the permission on this directory and file. Hope, this code will help you to find out which permission you need to assign for this user.
http://craigot.blogspot.com/2012/09/ssis-checking-filefolder-permissions.html

Comment: Thanks Shuvankar, I tried the code and the result was "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: User (Agent Service Logon Account) does not have permission to ReadData from folder E:\XXX", though the account is the member of the Administrators and Administrators have Full Control Access to the folder. Actually, after I gave the user itself Full Control Access to the folder, it succeeded without fail. It's difficult to understand as the agent job can at least read a file in the folder.